# document.querySelector with dynamic class name

Tags: javascript

I have a div with 3 classes, the third class (dynamic) changes

```
<div class="one two dynamic">test</div>
```

I need to select the element with class names 'one', 'two' and have a 3rd
class name of any name.

I've tried using `document.querySelector('.one.two.*')` - note the `*`

Any suggestions

edit: there are actually 5 classes and the third one (dynamic) is dynamically generated.
Sorry, I should have stated that originally as I appreciate that complicates the problem...

Comment: Why can't you just use `document.querySelector('.one.two')`?

Comment: @rnevius, becuase his requirement may be that there must be a third class, whatever class that is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thanks to Oriol who pointed me in the right direction!
Using his example I came up with this which returns the element with class "one two dynamic four five":

```
<body>
<p id="a" class="one two">a</p>
<p id="b" class="one two dynamic four five">b</p>
<p id="c" class="one two dynamic">c</p>
<p id="d" class="one two dynamic">d</p>

<script>
[].filter.call(document.querySelectorAll('.one.two'), function(el) {

    if(el.classList.toString().indexOf('four five') != -1){
      alert('id='+el.id);
      return el;
    }

})[0].style.background = 'orange';
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can:

1. Use `querySelectorAll` to get all the elements with the classes `one` and `two`.
2. Borrow `filter` to create an array with only those which have exactly 3 classes.
3. Get the first element in that array.

```js
[].filter.call(document.querySelectorAll('.one.two'), function(el) {
  return el.classList.length == 3;
})[0];
```

```js
[].filter.call(document.querySelectorAll('.one.two'), function(el) {
  return el.classList.length == 3;
})[0].style.background = 'orange';
```

```html
<p class="one two">one two</p>
<p class="one two three four">one two three four</p>
<p class="one two three">one two three</p>
<p class="one two three">one two three</p>
```

Comment: Alternatively, use `>= 3` if you want to impose at least 3 classes instead of exactly 3.

Comment: Where supported, it can use directly Array's [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method, instead of `filter`.